# White page on a live site

Tags: php

OK - here's the problem:

I have a Test site which works perfectly.

I have a page which fetches a number of data items from mysql and displays them for any specific user when logged on; the User has an option to edit those data items. The Edit page is displayed and the data items changed. When the button is pressed a White screen is displayed - the url is correct.

I know that the User is connected to the database (because the previous data is displayed, the data is displayed for editing on the next page and when the White Page is displayed there is no message saying, "Unable to connect."

I know that the programme works on my test bed (and loads, edits and displays new data) so there cannot be any misprints or punctuation errors with the code - it is just when it operates on the Live site it stops at this point.

It has got me confused!

The relevant code is:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='xxxxxx.php?view=$email'>View result</a>";
}

else {
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
}
?>
```

The Error Log shows:

```
[Thu Feb 21 06:38:17 2013] [error] [client xxxx] File does not exist: xxx_html/robots.txt
[Thu Feb 21 02:48:47 2013] [error] [client xxxx] File does not exist: xxx_html/404.shtml
[Thu Feb 21 02:48:47 2013] [error] [client xxxx] File does not exist: xxx_html/robots.tx
```

The code is correctly opened with `<?php`

Comment: You have to enable error reporting _before_ your script breaks.

Comment: Can you post the SQL query?

Comment: The SQL query is very long and entails 26 data items but starts:"$sql="UPDATE `quals2` SET qual_id='$qual_id', surname='$surname'   etc etc  and finishes .....other_quals='$other_quals'  WHERE qual_id='$qual_id'";

Comment: Please note that `mysql_query()` and other related functions are **deprecated**, and not recommended for use. You are advised to switch your code to use either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: On a production system, a blank white screen is considered preferable to displaying system error messages to the end user. For dev system, seeing the error on screen is useful, but for live site, keep it to the error log. So since this is a live site we're talking about and since you are able to get the messages from the error log, why do you need to see them on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand my question - I do not want to display the error, I want to know why my site is not working correctly in Live when it does so in Test. The Error log shows that the 'file does not exist' but clearly it does because it displays the correct url. What is missing from Live that exists in Test?